# Is there a way to replace a cell value in a sheet based on another specific value in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Good afternoon,

I tried to make the title as clear as possible and I realize that I probably failed, basically I have two sheets in a workbook, Sheet 1 is a sheet I use for Lookup Values (Data Validations with Drop-down lists are in Sheet 2), sorry if my terms are not good, i'm not an expert in Excel and speak mostly french.
My drop-down list in Sheet 2 looks up the Value in Sheet 1 Column A (Which are numbers) and in Column B is the text value that matches the numbers in my system.
What I want to do is set up the drop-down list to show me the text values in Column B and then run some kind of macro/formula to replace that value with the number value (Which is always the cell on the left of that value).

First question I ask here, been reading a bit so please let me know if anything is needed to further help me.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome. What does `show me the text values` mean? Show it in a `MsgBox`? Are you prepared to lose the text value or do you want to store it somewhere? BTW it could be helpful to know (see) what you have tried so far. You can edit your question by using the `edit` link below your post.

Comment: Hi, I honestly haven't tried anything yet as I don't know where to start.
I need to import data in my system from this excel sheet, this system only allows numbers imported from Excel and then converts them to text (Ex. 1 = Also Available in Blue).
Right now, my data validation list shows me the text, so I have to go back into the data validation sheet to see what number is assigned to that phrase, I would like to have a macro that allows me to switch the text to the value on the column to the left so I can import it straight into my system.

Comment: It is a little confusing, but I conclude the following: You have values in `Sheet1` columns `A` and `B`, and you have matching values from `Sheet1` column `B` in `Sheet2` column `B`. Now you want to lookup the values of `Sheet2` column `B` in `Sheet1` column `B` and overwrite (replace) the values with corresponding values of `Sheet1` column `A` e,g, with a click on a button.

Comment: If both sheets are in the same workbook, you can insert a formula in sheet2 cell A1 such as following `=Sheet1!A1`, this will populate value of sheet 2 cell A1 with value from sheet 1 cell A1.

Comment: @VBasic2008 Yes you got it, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 1):

### A Match Transfer

Adjust the values in the constants section.

```
Option Explicit

Sub getValues()

    Const Proc As String = "getValues"
    On Error GoTo resolveError

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    Const srcName As String = "Sheet1" ' Source Worksheet Name
    Const srcFirst As Long = 2    ' Source First Row Number
    Const srcValue As Long = 1    ' Source Value Column Number
    Const srcLookUp As Long = 2   ' Source Lookup Column Number
    Const tgtName As String = "Sheet2" ' Target Worksheet Name
    Const tgtFirst As Long = 2    ' Target First Row Number
    Const tgtLookUp As Long = 2   ' Target Lookup Column Number

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim Source(1) As Variant      ' Source 3D Array (Lookup and Value Arrays)
    Dim Target As Variant         ' Target (Column) Array (LookUp Array)
    Dim CurInd As Long            ' Current Index of Source Arrays
    Dim i As Long                 ' Target Array Row Counter
    Dim Transferred As Boolean    ' Success Checker

    ' Write columns to arrays.
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(srcName)
        Set rng = .Columns(srcLookUp).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If rng.Row < srcFirst Then Exit Sub
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(srcFirst, srcLookUp), rng)
        Source(0) = rng.Value
        Source(1) = rng.Offset(, srcValue - srcLookUp).Value
    End With
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(tgtName)
        Set rng = .Columns(tgtLookUp).Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If rng Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
        If rng.Row < tgtFirst Then Exit Sub
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(tgtFirst, tgtLookUp), rng)
        Target = rng.Value
    End With

    ' Lookup the values of Target Array (Target) in Source Lookup Array
    ' (Source(0)) and replace Current Value of Target Array with values found
    ' in the same row of Source Value Array (Source(1)).
    For i = 1 To UBound(Target)
        On Error Resume Next
        CurInd = WorksheetFunction.Match(Target(i, 1), Source(0), 0)
        If Err.Number = 0 Then
            ' found a match
            Target(i, 1) = Source(1)(CurInd, 1)
        Else
            ' if no match found
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0
    Next i
    On Error GoTo resolveError

    ' Write modified Target Array to Target Range.
    rng.Value = Target

    Transferred = True

CleanExit:
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    ' Inform user.
    If Transferred Then
        MsgBox "'" & Proc & "' has successfully transferred the data.", _
          vbInformation, "Transfer Success"
    End If

    Exit Sub

resolveError:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error occurred in '" & Proc & "'." & vbCr _
         & "Run-time error '" & Err.Number & "':" & vbCr & Err.Description _
           , vbCritical, Proc & " Error"
    On Error GoTo 0
    Resume CleanExit

End Sub
```